# Use the updated state in the another function as parameter

Tags: reactjs, onchange

I have an input field and when I enter any value into the input field ,I am updating the state with the entered value . Then I want to use the updated state value in a function which increments this updated state value.

**My Root component**

```
class App extends Component{

 state ={
  data:0
  };

render() {

  return (

   <div className="App">

     <div id="inside">
      <Increment change={this.changeHandler} value={this.state.data} number={this.state.data}
       incrementHandler={this.incrementHandler} decrementHandler={this.decrementHandler}
      />

      <br></br>

      </div>
      <br />

    </div>
  );

}
}
export default App;
```

**My increment function**

**IncrementHandler is the function to execute upon button click**

```
  incrementHandler =()=>{

    // getting the previous value in the state using prevState keyword

    this.setState(state =>({
      data:this.state.data+1
     }));


};
```

**My change changehandler function**

```
changeHandler =(event)=>{

      this.setState({data:event.target.value});

    };
```

**File I am importing in my root component**

```
  //Function contains input field
 const Increment =(props)=>{

     return(

         <div className="count">

         <input type="text" onChange={props.change} value={props.value}/>

         <h1 >Count:{props.number} </h1>

         <br></br>

         <br></br>

         <button onClick={props.incrementHandler} type="button" 
          className="btn btn-success" id ="btn">Increment </button>

          <button onClick={props.decrementHandler} type="button" 
           className="btn btn-warning" id="btn">Decrement </button>
         </div>

        )

    };

    export default Increment;
```

While clicking the increment button ,the updated state value have to be 
      incremented ,but it is appending.

Example : If I enter 124 in the input field , after clicking the increment button,the value should be 125,but the value showing for me is 1241

Answer (score 1):

Your input is of type text. So when you increment, the string value is concated.
'1'+ 1 is 11 not 2.

change your input to

```
<input type="number" onChange={props.change} value={props.value}/>
```

or else use parseInt method.(But for that you have to make sure the input value is always number)

Comment: Please accept the anser if it solved your issue.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 incrementHandler =()=>{

    // getting the previous value in the state using prevState keyword

    this.setState(state =>({
      data:parseInt(this.state.data)+1
     }));


};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";
function App() {
  const [num, setnum] = React.useState(0);

  const increment = () => {
    setnum(parseFloat(num) + 1);
  };
  const decrement = () => {
    setnum(num - 1);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="number" value={num} onChange={e => setnum(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={increment}>inc</button>
      <button onClick={decrement}>dec</button>
      <p>{num}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```